# AppInsights - Logging the Network tab

Tags: performance, browser, azure-application-insights

I've been asked to get something similar to the waterfall like report that can be found in most browsers network tabs.

We have the [End-to-End Transactions report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-transaction-diagnostics#transaction-diagnostics-experience) in App Insights, which is close, but for the pageViews section I am only seeing the AJAX dependencies. What about all the other categories like XHR/JS/CSS/Img/Media/Font/Doc/WS/Manifest/Other (As seen in Chrome network tab filters)?

I was looking at this snippet a JS and realized this may be everything in the network tab. `window.performance.getEntries()`

I'm wondering if its an advisable endeavour to try and log all these other categories as dependencies to App Insights?

Thoughts,
Devin

Comment: By the way, you can check the things like js/css etc. in the performance blade.

Comment: Ok sorry for the delay. I went to Browser, Performance, Dependencies and all I saw was AJAXs. Can you confirm? Possibly include a screenshot? Maybe I have something configured incorrectly or have to update my AppInsights browser SDK?

Comment: When I get back company, I can show you some screenshots. Not sure if we are on the same page, but we can discuss more after I post the screenshot to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to see the css/js in Performance blade, screenshot as below:
[image]

Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding.

And you'd better provide your sample code and screenshot about your portal, then I will continue on it.

Comment: Those are operations not dependencies. I am under the impression that operations account for request that are only on your server. This would not cover resources that are being fetched from other sources.

Comment: do you mean that in your case, you have a dependency which calls css, js etc?

Comment: No I have an operation (ex. home page) which has css/js/img on cdns and other servers